# How to run anaconda and launch jupyter notebook with python 3.9.6?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, zsh, macos-big-sur

I am on macOS Big Sur v11.5.1 with python3 v3.9.6 and since updating my OS and my Python can no longer run anaconda or launch jupyter notebook.

When I use the terminal command `jupyter notebook` I get:

zsh: command not found: jupyter

So I checked anaconda (which the terminal had said had been successfully installed) with `anaconda --version` and got:

zsh: command not found: anaconda

Prior to the Big Sur and Python 3.9.6 update (I was previously running 3.6) I was able to just type `jupyter notebook` and it would launch in my browser. I'd like to be able to do that again now. Is the issue that anaconda doesn't run on python 3.9? Or that the zsh shell isn't recognizing anaconda, conda, etc?

Thank you!

Comment: `anaconda --version` is not a valid command. Did you mean `conda --version`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your jupyter was installed in conda base env.

Find out where your anaconda installed.
For example, I installed it in home directory,
so I do following steps:

```
echo "source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" > ~/.bashrc
```

then you have to

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

After that you will get back your conda.